# Making a Simple Database Program in C#

Tags: c#, database, text, analysis

I'm currently writing a [simple text analysis program in C#](https://github.com/austinprete/Text-Analysis).  Currently it takes simple statistics from the text and prints them out.  However, I need to get it to the point where in input mode you input sample text, specifying an author, and it writes the statistics to a database entry of that specific author.  Then in a different mode the program will take text, and see if it can accurately identify the author by pulling averages from the DB files and comparing the text's statistics to sample statistics.  What I need help with is figuring out the best way to make a database out of text statistics.  Is there some library I could use for this?  Or should I simply do simple reading and writing from text files that I'll store the information in?  Any and all ideas are welcome, as I'm struggling to come up with a solution to this problem.

Thanks, 
PardonMyRhetoric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use and XmlSerializer to persist your data to file really easily.  There are numerous tutorials you can find on google that will teach you how in just a few minutes.  However, most of them want to show you how to add attributes to your properties to customize the way it serializes, so I'll just point out that those aren't really necessary.  So long as you have the [Serializeable] tag over your class all you need is something that looks like this to save:

```
void Save()
{
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter("somefile.xml")) 
        (new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass))).Serialize(sw, this);
}
```

and something like this in a function to read it:

```
MyClass Load()
{
    XmlSerializer xSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
    using (var sr = new StreamReader("somefile.xml"))
        return (MyClass)xSer.Deserialize(sr);
}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention:  It will serialize any public properties.  So anything you want to save/read needs to be in a public property with a public getter and public setter.

Comment: Thanks, looks like something that could be useful to me.  I'll look into this method and LINQ and see which I feel is better used for this specific project.

Comment: @PardonMyRhetoric: linq by itself (aka linq2objects) won't help you persist data, it just gives you a way to make queries on your data.  You could use linq2sql to persist to a database but then that's defeating the goal of keeping things simple and not needing a database.  That's why I suggested serialization as a way to persist your data, and then you can use linq2sql to work with it more easily.

Comment: Just fyi, the code I wrote above would go inside of your class and you can rename 'MyClass' to whatever the name of your class is.  That's literally all the code you need.  The Save function works how you'd expect.  However, you'll probably want to make the Load method static ("public static MyClass Load()").  Then to load your data back into the class you'd say "var data = MyClass.Load()".

Comment: I see now.  Well I might just use this code in that case, obviously changed a little bit for my program/classes. I do need persistent data, otherwise it's a useless application.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think in this stage you'll need a database. Try to select appropriate data structures from the .NET framework itself. Try to use dictionary or lists, don't use arrays for this, and the methods you write will become simpler. Try to learn LINQ - it's like queries to database, but to regular data structures. When you'll get this and the project will grow, try to add a database.

Comment: I'll have to look into LINQ more than I have.  I never thought of doing it that.  This project is something I'm doing mainly to learn programming a little better but I'm also relating it to a required science project at school, so I do have a deadline of sorts, so I'll need to learn fairly quickly if I choose to do it with LINQ.

Comment: Linq is not that complicated; I learned it mostly from [here](http://www.csharphelp.com/2010/01/linq-using-c-linq-operators/)

Comment: Thanks man, those examples convinced me LINQ is what I'm looking for.  I'm sure I'll be able to learn it enough to start working on my program's author identification feature by tomorrow or Monday.  Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah man, one question though, using LINQ how can these be persistent after the program is closed?  I need it to have the same "database" of sorts available each time it's opened.  Sorry if I'm missing something obvious.